# Excluding an attribute from __setattr__ and __getattr__ in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, setattr

I'm trying to implement a `Config` class that holds and keeps track of an arbitrary amount of `Settings`. I'd like to get and set the `Settings` like `c = Config(<CONTAINER_OF_POSSIBLE_SETTINGS>); c.x = 1; print(c.foo)` where `x` and `foo` are some `Settings` (or their `name` attribute) given to the `Config` during initialization. So I tried overwriting the `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` methods. But I'm running into an infinite recursion problem. Here is the bare-bones version of what I have so far:

```
#config.py

class Setting:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Setting(name: {self.name}, value: {self.value})"


class Config:
    #_settings = {}
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self._settings = settings

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        try:
            self._settings[name].value = value
        except KeyError as err:
            try:
                return super(Config, self).__setattr__(name, value)
            except AttributeError:
                raise err

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._settings[name].value
        except KeyError as err:
            try:
                return super(Config, self).__getattribute__(name)
            except AttributeError:
                raise err


class Interface:
    def __init__(self):
        settings = {
            s.name: s for s in [
                Setting("x", 1.),
                Setting("y", 2.),
            ]
        }
        self.config = Config(settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = Interface()
    print(i.config._settings)
    i.config.x = 9.
    print(i.config._settings)
    #print(Config._settings)
```

The idea was that `__setattr__` would try to look up the attribute name in the `self._settings` dictionary or - if it can't find a `Setting` with the name - set the attribute the "usual way" by calling `super().__setattr__`.
But running this results in:

```
$ python config.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "config.py", line 52, in <module>
    i = Interface()
  File "config.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.config = Config(settings)
  File "config.py", line 15, in __init__
    self._settings = settings
  File "config.py", line 20, in __setattr__
    self._settings[name].value = value
  File "config.py", line 31, in __getattr__
    return self._settings[name].value
  File "config.py", line 31, in __getattr__
    return self._settings[name].value
  File "config.py", line 31, in __getattr__
    return self._settings[name].value
  [Previous line repeated 991 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

From what I read in other threads, the problem is that `self._settings` in `Config.__init__()` calls `__setattr__` which in turn calls `__getattr__`. And both methods try to access `self._settings` which causes the recursion. I'm not even getting to part where I try to access the dictionary's items.

One "hot-fix" I found was adding `_settings` as a class attribute to `Config`. After un-comenting the two lines in the code above the program yields:

```
$ python config.py
{'x': Setting(name: x, value: 1.0), 'y': Setting(name: y, value: 2.0)}
{'x': Setting(name: x, value: 9.0), 'y': Setting(name: y, value: 2.0)}
{}
```

But now I have this empty class attribute which is not what I want. And it shows that I don't fully understand initialization, `__setattr__` , and `__getattr__`.
What I'm trying to do is telling `Config` that the `_settings` attribute should be handled differently. Unfortunately, I can't just have all the `Settings` be class attributes of `Config` since they (can) depend on the `Config` and/or `Interface` class.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `self._settings` by `self.__dict__['_settings']`.

Comment: That works, thanks! Another solution I thought of is having `Config` inherit from `dict`. That way, I don't even need `self._settings` and simple use `self` in `__setattr__` etc